# Можно ли дать хранимой процедуре права на выбор из другой схемы?

Tags: oracle, plsql, процедуры

Надо чтобы пользователь не имел доступа к другой схеме, но хранимая процедура могла обратиться к другой схеме.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создайте процедуру в своей схеме, дайте пользователю grant execute и добавьте ему синоним для удобства пользователя (чтобы не вызывать через полное имя). Или создавайте процедуру в его схеме, но с с authid current_user.